# Laravel Validation rules: required_without

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have two fields: `Email` and `Telephone`

i want to create a validation where one of two fields are required and if one or both fields are set, it should be the correct Format.

I tried this, but it doesnt work, i need both though

```
 public static array $createValidationRules = [
        'email' => 'required_without:telephone|email:rfc',
        'telephone' => 'required_without:email|numeric|regex:/^\d{5,15}$/',

    ];
```

Comment: what is the validation error you are getting

Comment: i dont get a validation error, the validate just says both fields are required

Comment: If you haven't filled both fileds that what you will get. Are you sure that you are filling either on of these fileds

Comment: And you need only either email or telephone but not both right ??

Comment: only 1 of both is required but it should also possible to set both fields @ManojKiranAppathurai

Comment: Try filling them both.

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai filling both, works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is correct that both fields produce the `required_without` error message if both are empty. This error message clearly says that the field must be filled if the other is not. You may [change](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages) the message if needed:

```
$messages = [
    'email.required_without' => 'foo',
    'telephone.required_without' => 'bar',
];
```

However, you must add the `nullable` rule, so the format rules don't apply when the field is empty:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => ['required_without:telephone', 'nullable', 'email:rfc'],
    'telephone' => ['required_without:email', 'nullable', 'numeric', 'regex:/^\d{5,15}$/'],
];
```

Furthermore: [It is recommended](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex) writing the rules as array, especially when using `regex`.